# Bitwise operators - when/how do you use the operators &, |, ^, >> etc?

Tags: operators, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, bit

I know what they do, I just don't understand when you'd get a use for them..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you need to manipulate individual bits of a chunk of data (like a byte or an int). This happens frequently, for example, in algorithms dealing with:

- encryption
- compression
- audio / video processing
- networking (protocols)
- persistence (file formats)
- etc.

Answer (score 2):

I've used them for bit masks before.  Say you have an item that has a list of items that can have either a yes or no value (options on a car for instance).  You can assign one integer column that will give a value for every option by assigning each option to a binary digit in the number.

```
Example: 5 = 101 in binary
that would mean:
option 1 - yes
option 2 - no
option 3 - yes
```

If you were to query on this you would use bitwise & or | operators to select the correct items.

[Here is a good article](http://www.vipan.com/htdocs/bitwisehelp.html) that goes over it in more detail.

Answer (score 1):

One example is if you have an (A)RGB color stored as a 32 bit integer and you want to extract the individual color components:

```
red = (rgb >> 16) & 0x000000ff;
green = (rgb >> 8) & 0x000000ff;
blue = rgb & 0x000000ff;
```

Of course as a high level programmer you would normally prefer to use a library function to do this rather than fiddling with bits yourself. But the library might be implemented using bitwise operations.

Comment: @DarkLightA: If you're asking why the operation is necassary, it's called masking - you only want to see the bits you are interested in - the rest are set to zero. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mask_%28computing%29#Masking_bits_to_0 If you are asking why the unnecessary zeros are there, it's just to be clear that we're dealing with 32-bit integers, but the leading zeros can be omitted if you wish.